# single select filter control in datastudio

Tags: looker-studio

I am using google data studio to create charts. I am using a filter control to select values(ex. Memory Type) as filter to filter a chart and a table . It currently displays 2 values
**Free** and **Used**. [image]

There is a checkbox next to the selection . Is it possible to have the checkbox removed, so that I can use it as a **single select drop-down** list or is there any other control to achive the same?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Single Select [Filter Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144) should do the trick. Optionally, a default selection could be added (so that a value would be selected by default).

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/9b1fc4a4-e354-4e99-a10b-433246885cf3) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]